# how to search documents and update metadata using REST API in MarkLogic server?

Tags: marklogic

How can I assign documents obtained by a [QBE](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_46421) to a collection using REST API in MarkLogic Server? I currently use this QBE:

```
<q:qbe xmlns:q="http://marklogic.com/appservices/querybyexample">
  <q:query><ALBUM>Pop</ALBUM></q:query>
  <q:response><q:extract><TITLE></TITLE></q:extract></q:response>
</q:qbe>
```

If QBE cannot be used, what else can I use to search document by some criteria and update the collection metadata therein?

Answer (score 2):

You can use QBE to bring back a list of documents to the client.

You can then do a bulk write that updates the collections on those documents (but not the content or other metadata).

Bulk update of metadata in the REST API is described here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk#id_88873

The Java and Node.js APIs provide an interface for bulk update of metadata.

The best approach is to page through the matching documents in batches of 100.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks for your response ehennum. My question now is how to convert this qbe query result into a post body of the next bulk request? Should it be done manually?

Comment: Yes, you will have to write some client code to generate the bulk write request from the QBE response. To simplify the response, you can turn off the snippets with the "none" value http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/qbe#id_83560 . On the client, get the document URIs from each result and use that to construct the bulk write request.